# Import Dump File into Oracle Express 11g ORA-01950

Tags: import, tablespace, oracle-export-dump

I'm trying to import a some dmp files from a client into a locally installed Oracle Express 11.2g and have been running into some problems.

The import command I am using is:

```
imp system/****** file=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump\rrcdw_pdq_ownr_1.dmp full=y
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'

TESTSPACE is a tablespace I created while trying to import the data.  I already tried creating additional users and granting them unlimited quota on the tablespace, and granting them DBA privileges.

Below is the full output I get when running the import command.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser>imp system/******* file=C:\oraclexe\app\oracl
e\admin\XE\dpdump\rrcdw_pdq_ownr_1.dmp full=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu May 16 08:48:58 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Productio
n

Export file created by EXPORT:V09.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by EXP_USR, not by you

import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
export client uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion)
IMP-00046: using FILESIZE value from export file of 2147483648
. importing EXP_USR's objects into SYSTEM
. importing PDQ_OWNR's objects into PDQ_OWNR
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "BASETB_SIZE" ("TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "TABLE_SIZE_MB" NUMB"
 "ER)  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 F"
 "REELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           LOGGING NOCOMPRESS"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "CHAINED_ROWS" ("OWNER_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "TABLE_NAME" VARCHA"
 "R2(30), "CLUSTER_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "PARTITION_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "SUBPAR"
 "TITION_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "HEAD_ROWID" ROWID, "ANALYZE_TIMESTAMP" DATE)  P"
 "CTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 FREELIS"
 "TS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           LOGGING NOCOMPRESS"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "COLUMN_AVG" ("TB" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, "ROW_SIZE" NU"
 "MBER)  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 131072"
 " FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           LOGGING NOCOMPRES"
 "S"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "COLUMN_COUNTS" ("TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "COLUMN_COUNT" NUM"
 "BER, "ROW_COUNT" NUMBER, "ROW_AVG_SIZE" NUMBER, "TABLE_SIZE_MB" NUMBER)  PC"
 "TFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 FREELIST"
 "S 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           LOGGING NOCOMPRESS"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "COLUMN_YEARLY_COUNTS" ("TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), "ROW_AVG_SI"
 "ZE" NUMBER, "YEARLY_COUNT" NUMBER, "YEARLY_TABLE_SIZE_MB" NUMBER, "CYCLE_YE"
 "AR_COL" CHAR(4))  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INI"
 "TIAL 131072 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           LOGGIN"
 "G NOCOMPRESS"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "GP_COUNTY" ("COUNTY_NO" CHAR(3) NOT NULL ENABLE, "COUNTY_FIPS"
 "_CODE" CHAR(3), "COUNTY_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), "DISTRICT_NO" CHAR(2) NOT NULL "
 "ENABLE, "DISTRICT_NAME" CHAR(2), "ON_SHORE_FLAG" CHAR(1), "ONSHORE_ASSC_CNT"
 "Y_FLAG" CHAR(1))  PCTFREE 2 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INIT"
 "IAL 524288 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           NOLOGGI"
 "NG NOCOMPRESS CACHE PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT)"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "GP_DATE_RANGE_CYCLE" ("OLDEST_PROD_CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH" VARCHAR2"
 "(6) NOT NULL ENABLE, "NEWEST_PROD_CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH" VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL EN"
 "ABLE, "NEWEST_SCHED_CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH" VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL ENABLE, "GAS_EXT"
 "RACT_DATE" DATE, "OIL_EXTRACT_DATE" DATE)  PCTFREE 2 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 "
 "MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 524288 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)         "
 "                  NOLOGGING NOCOMPRESS CACHE PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INST"
 "ANCES DEFAULT)"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "GP_DISTRICT" ("DISTRICT_NO" CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, "DISTRIC"
 "T_NAME" CHAR(2), "OFFICE_PHONE_NO" VARCHAR2(10), "OFFICE_LOCATION" VARCHAR2"
 "(50))  PCTFREE 2 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 524288 "
 "FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1)                           NOLOGGING NOCOMPRE"
 "SS CACHE PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT)"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "OG_COUNTY_CYCLE" ("COUNTY_NO" CHAR(3) NOT NULL ENABLE, "DISTR"
 "ICT_NO" CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, "CYCLE_YEAR" CHAR(4) NOT NULL ENABLE, "CYC"
 "LE_MONTH" CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, "CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH" VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL "
 "ENABLE, "CNTY_OIL_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_OIL_ALLOW" NUMBER(11, 0), "
 ""CNTY_OIL_ENDING_BAL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_GAS_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CN"
 "TY_GAS_ALLOW" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_GAS_LIFT_INJ_VOL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_C"
 "OND_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_COND_LIMIT" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_COND_EN"
 "DING_BAL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_CSGD_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_CSGD_LIM"
 "IT" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_CSGD_GAS_LIFT" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_OIL_TOT_DISP" "
 "NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_GAS_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(11, 0), "CNTY_COND_TOT_DISP" NUMB"
 "ER(11, 0), "CNTY_CSGD_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(11, 0), "COUNTY_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), "
 ""DISTRICT_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), "OIL_GAS_CODE" CHAR(1))  PCTFREE 5 PCTUSED 40"
 " INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 1048576 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUP"
 "S 1)                           NOLOGGING NOCOMPRESS CACHE PARALLEL ( DEGREE"
 " DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT)"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1950:
 "CREATE TABLE "OG_COUNTY_LEASE_CYCLE" ("OIL_GAS_CODE" CHAR(1) NOT NULL ENABL"
 "E, "DISTRICT_NO" CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, "LEASE_NO" VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL E"
 "NABLE, "CYCLE_YEAR" CHAR(4) NOT NULL ENABLE, "CYCLE_MONTH" CHAR(2) NOT NULL"
 " ENABLE, "COUNTY_NO" CHAR(3) NOT NULL ENABLE, "OPERATOR_NO" VARCHAR2(6), "F"
 "IELD_NO" VARCHAR2(8), "CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH" VARCHAR2(6), "FIELD_TYPE" CHAR(2),"
 " "GAS_WELL_NO" VARCHAR2(6), "PROD_REPORT_FILED_FLAG" CHAR(1), "CNTY_LSE_OIL"
 "_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_OIL_ALLOW" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_OIL_E"
 "NDING_BAL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_GAS_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_GA"
 "S_ALLOW" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_GAS_LIFT_INJ_VOL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_"
 "COND_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_COND_LIMIT" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_"
 "COND_ENDING_BAL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_CSGD_PROD_VOL" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY"
 "_LSE_CSGD_LIMIT" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_CSGD_GAS_LIFT" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY"
 "_LSE_OIL_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_GAS_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNT"
 "Y_LSE_COND_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(9, 0), "CNTY_LSE_CSGD_TOT_DISP" NUMBER(9, 0), ""
 "DISTRICT_NAME" CHAR(2), "LEASE_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), "OPERATOR_NAME" VARCHAR2"
 "(50), "FIELD_NAME" VARCHAR2(32), "COUNTY_NAME" VARCHAR2(50))  PCTFREE 5 PCT"
 "USED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 10485760 FREELISTS 1 FREELI"
 "ST GROUPS 1)                           NOLOGGING NOCOMPRESS CACHE PARALLEL "
 "( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT)"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1950 encountered
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TESTSPACE'
```